# Vaadin custom field validation

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a Vaadin 23 component which is a `CustomField<String>` that consists of 3 `TextField` parts. In each text field, a part of the `String` is entered. The model value is calculated simply by concatenating the values of the text fields.
The custom field is bound using a binder which is used to validate before saving.

I'm setting the "error" theme on the text fields when the custom field is marked as invalid. I'm able to configure a default `Validator` for the custom field (by making it implement `HasValidator`), which generally works well, but the problem is that it fires too soon: when I move from the first `TextField` to the next, it already validates the whole value, which is missing the second and third part. But I'd rather not inform the user that there is a validation error when she is just entering the values.

Of course I could make the validator return `ok()` when any of the parts are missing, but when the user attempts to save, I do want to prevent this and signal the error. How should I do this?

This is the custom field implementation:

```
public class MyField extends CustomField<String> implements HasValidator<String> {
    private final TextField part1 = new TextField();
    private final TextField part2 = new TextField();
    private final TextField part3 = new TextField();

    public MyField() {
        super("");
        add(part1, part2, part3);
    }

    @Override
    public void setInvalid(boolean invalid) {
        super.setInvalid(invalid);
        part1.setInvalid(invalid);
        part2.setInvalid(invalid);
        part3.setInvalid(invalid);
        setErrorThemes(invalid);
    }

    private void setErrorThemes(boolean set) {
        part1.setThemeName("error", set);
        part2.setThemeName("error", set);
        part3.setThemeName("error", set);
    }

    @Override
    public Validator<String> getDefaultValidator() {
        return (value, context) -> {
            boolean valid = ... // validation
            return valid ? ok() : error("Not valid");
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String generateModelValue() {
        return part1.getValue() + part2.getValue() + part3.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setPresentationValue(String value) {
        // set individual part values
        part1.setValue(...);
        part2.setValue(...);
        part3.setValue(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the whole field is required, returning null for missing input and
validating OK, would give you roughly, what you want, but then it will
no longer work for partial input in a non-required-scenario.  Therefor,
is the current behaviour, but with more selective invalid/error-markings
(e.g. only on parts, with a problem) the more user-friendly?

Comment: @cfrick I want to prevent at all times to commit a partial input to the model (and DB), so validating OK when it's actually not, won't do it. (btw also doing modulo 97 check on the input, not just required/not-required).
That said, I have a hack to check (using focus and blur listeners) if any of the parts are focused, which won't be the case when the save button is pressed. So in that case I could validate OK.

Comment: Yep, so what about making the separation of "incomplete" and "erroneous"
clearer to the user like only marking invalid/error-theme on fields with
problems.  Also if this is just one IBAN I'd argue, that multiple fields
is not so great UX, because you would have to make pasting work properly
over multiple fields.

Comment: @cfrick I'm not sure what you mean: if the user forgets 1 digit and presses "save", it is "incomplete" but we should definitely mark the field as "erroneous". If the 3rd part is missing a digit it could be because one was skipped in the 1st part (I'm auto-jumping to the next field), and in case of mod 97 fail it could be any part as well, so it's OK to mark all parts I think.

It's not IBAN but a structured payment communication like +++123/1234/12328+++ where the user enters only the digits and the + and / characters are static content around the text fields.